# Convert any character to escape characters

Tags: php

Escape character for "$" is

```
&#36;
```

Is there a native php function to convert and get escape characters from any kind of input?

htmlspecialchars is converting ok but not for all input strings... it won't work for "$"

For reference - http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php

EDIT:

```
echo htmlentities("$"); //output "$", not "&#36;"

echo htmlspecialchars("$"); //output "$", not "&#36;"
```

Comment: `htmlentities` and `html_entity_decode`

Comment: Try: added PHP ver 5.4.0 <?php
$string = 'te$t';
$string = htmlentities($string, ENT_SUBSTITUTE);
echo $string;
?>

Comment: What are you up to? Converting that dollar sign into the numeric character reference isn't needing very much magic: `echo str_replace('$', '&#36', '$ and something');` - but is does not really make sense to escape the dollar sign just because there is an NCR available. So the answer is: NO, there isn't a native function in PHP. But why are you asking? I bet you think this will solve one of your problems, but it really only works around the real problem that you haven't told us yet.

Answer (score 0):

found in the manual user notes, tested seems to work on all my tests.

```
<?php
function superentities( $str ){
    // get rid of existing entities else double-escape
    $str = html_entity_decode(stripslashes($str),ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
    $ar = preg_split('/(?<!^)(?!$)/u', $str );  // return array of every multi-byte character
    foreach ($ar as $c){
        $o = ord($c);
        if ( (strlen($c) > 1) || /* multi-byte [unicode] */
            ($o <32 || $o > 126) || /* <- control / latin weirdos -> */
            ($o >33 && $o < 40) ||/* quotes + ambersand */
            ($o >59 && $o < 63) /* html */
        ) {
            // convert to numeric entity
            $c = mb_encode_numericentity($c,array (0x0, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff), 'UTF-8');
        }
        $str2 .= $c;
    }
    return $str2;
}

echo superentities('$'); //&#36;

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with php.htmlspecialchars:
[htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: htmlspecialchars is converting ok but not for all input strings... it won't work for "$"

Comment: Not sure if PHP has a native function for this

Answer (score -1):

Use htmlentities to convert all possible characters - [read more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Comment: echo htmlentities("$"); will output "$", but not "&#36;"

Comment: That is true. Though, in defense of the function, a dollar sign is perfectly html safe, and it doesn't have it's own html entity (such as the yen symbol, for example). Though I understand that that's not the functionality you were after.

Comment: @Dagon: This is wrong, there is only a limited set of entities defined. Note that "entity" means giving a name to a character, like `&copy;` for the copyright sign. Do not confuse them with the numeric character references like `&#36;` - these are no entities, but often get mistaken for being them. And also note that only characters included in the unicode standard have numeric character references - but there are more characters known to mankind, than in unicode. So not even "every character has a NCR" is true.

Comment: true, the OP used the Numeric character references in his question so i based my answer on that